# Select parent element of datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am new to JQuery and JS.

I have  element inside which I am using JQuery datepicker. On datepicker `select` event I want to get a reference to the parent `<td>` element. How do I do it.
Thanks in advance.

```
<td>
    <input type='text'/>
</td>
```

Comment: plz share relevent html code also..

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ Please check this page for all tutorial and help on jQuery DatePicker...

Comment: Check this out too. jQuery parent() http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: you can use `parent()` method to select parent element.

Comment: I have tried parent(), but it gives me reference to current window instead of enclosing td tag.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NdN9H/48/

Comment: @Kartikeya even using `this` works, not sure what could be OP's issue http://jsfiddle.net/NdN9H/49/

Comment: As you are getting `window` from parent(), there is *something else* going on. please provide the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `parent()`, but it is safer to use `closest` (in case of DOM changes):

Inside the select event `this` should be the `datepicker` element.

```
var parentTD = $(this).closest('td');
```

A number of plugins have a habit of changing the DOM around the element they are attached to but `closest` will search up the ancestors *until* it finds a match.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NdN9H/52/

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** As discussed in comments, as the parent needs to be selected in an event handler where you have access to datepicker element using `$(this)` there is no need to use `id`

You should try putting an id on your input element:

```
        <td>
           <input id="mydatepicker" type='text'/>
       </td>
```

In javascript you can use the `parent` function to select the parent of your input element

```
$("#mydatepicker").parent()
```

If this doesn't work as expected, may be the datepicker plugin has wrapped your `input` element in another element. You'll need to inspect the DOM in browser to find out the final DOM structure surrounding your element.

See http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: Why each time there is a targeting problem, someone comes with an `add ID` solution?!

Comment: You are right, the other solutions are better, I missed the part in the questions where OP said that he wants to do this on `select` event where you have reference to datepicker itself using `$(this)`

Comment: Ok i see what you did then ;)

Comment: thanks TrueBlueAussie and others for your suggestions. Really thankful to all of you.